# ASP.net MVC - authentication cookie and redirects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-cookies

I am looking for a bit of a point in the right direction...

We have an MVC site, with a variety of virtual directories that all point at the same code, e.g.

```
https://www.x.com/dir1
https://www.x.com/dir2
```

The different virtual directories are used partly for business reasons due to the URL 'content' and partly to control how the site is skinned.

The sites are locked down for access using forms authentication, and I am trying to track down a slightly elusive issue.

A user logs into the site using the url 'dir1', authenticates fine, SetAuthCookie is called.

We have code that runs on OnActionExecuting throughout the site - it takes the logged in user and determines which virtual directory they should be accessing (one per user) and if they are in the wrong URL, will redirect them, e.g. (simplified code):

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (Authenticated && UserIsNotInCorrectDirectory())
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("https://www.x.com/dir2");
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is this - if I start a fresh browser (using firefox at the minute, to view the cookies) and do the following:

1. Log into the site using the 'dir1' url.
2. I get authenticated fine - I can see the set-cookie http header containing our auth cookie.  This response will also redirect me to 'dir2'.
3. On the subsequent page, when I view the cookies, the auth cookie is not there - this is the problem.

To add to my confusion, if I then bring up the login page again (same browser, session not closed), and try this again, it works.  Anybody got a clue?

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that your `OnActionExecuting` filter is getting in the way of your login form and your session cookie is getting lost when you overwrite the result. In case this code resides in an attribute, I would try removing the attribute from your `Login` action and see if that works.

Comment: That would be my bet as well, but I am looking for detail as to why it is happening so I can mitigate it.  This redirect has to happen.

Comment: I understand. I was not suggesting you to remove the redirect altogether; I meant to remove it from your Login action *only*. Not just for troubleshooting the issue at hand but also because it kind of makes sense; after all, how will you know whether the user is in the correct directory or not if he hasn't logged in yet?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, this redirect happens after the post to the login controller, i.e. after we know that they are authenticated.